# Webpack is not minimiziing my JavaScript files in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Im new to react.js and currently working on a react.js project which runs 100% ok with development environment without any errors. After i build the project in production mode it will not minify my javascript files. But my scss files are get minified.

```
const path = require("path");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js",
    vendor: "./src/vendor.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contentHash].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "imgs",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + "/app/index.html",
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "[name].[contentHash].css" }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Please someone help me to solve this problem and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can u please put your development webpack config file as well?

Comment: There isn't any big deff compare to my dev and prod config files. only difference is i dont have opitmization key in my dev file. thats it.

Comment: running a react application is a little bit fishy with the all above configurations. You have mentioned that your project is running without any error. Are you sure that you don't have any other webpack files that pointing to while you run in development mode?

Comment: You can add default minimizers by adding in your array of minimizers `'...'`. "Basically, `'...'` is [a shortcut to access the default configuration value](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4b4ca3bb53f36a5b8fc6bc1bd976ed7af161bd80/lib/config/defaults.js#L98-L108) webpack would otherwise set for us." — [Optimization | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationminimizer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default javascript minimizer plugin for webpack is **TerserPlugin**. When you setting `minimizer` attribute under the `optimizaton`, it will override the default values provided by webpack itself. To overcome this problem add TerserPlugin to your `webpack.config.js` file and pass it to the `minimizer` attribute.

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin(),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      minify: {
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
},
```

Comment: As per webpack documentation terser will only minify your js files and not CSS file. He is using MiniCssExtractPlugin for separating CSS and js files in build. How will it help to minify CSS files?

Comment: Yes @DhruviMakvana, you are right. terser is not responsible for CSS and I posted my answer to resolve only his js minify issue. not related to CSS minification. In the question also he is stating about a js minification problem. not about a CSS minification problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you only have minimization for your scss files, if you want to minify your javascript files aswell, you'll need a plugin such as [Uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin), you just import it on the top and add it to the optimization.minimizer like it says in plugin page example:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
 
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

MiniCssExtractPlugin will extract your CSS into a separate file and It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS. It won't minify your CSS files.

Import `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` for minification. You can configure minification based on your environment.

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const { getIfUtils } = require('webpack-config-utils')
const {ifProduction, ifNotProduction} = getIfUtils(process.env.NODE_ENV)

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.s?css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: ifProduction(true, false),
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I see that your minimizer list only contains the `cssMinimizerPlugin` and does not extend the default terser minimizer. Will this also minify javascript files in prod which seems to be the OP's question? If so, how?